# Definition of symmetrically ordered operator for multi-mode case?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, phase-space, wigner-transform, deformation-quantization

As I know, Wigner function is useful for evaluating the expectation value of an operator. But first you have to write it in a symmetrically ordered form. For example:

$$a^\dagger a = \frac{a^\dagger a + a a^\dagger -1}{2}$$

For single mode case where there is  only one pair of creation and destroy operator the symmetrically ordered operator is defined. But for multi-mode case,how is it defined? For example, how would we write 
$$a_1^\dagger a_1 a_2^\dagger a_2$$
in a symmetrically ordered form (such that we could easily evaluate its expectation value using Wigner function)?

Comment: I have a guess that "mode wise" symmetrically ordered operator is just general  symmetrically ordered operator in multi-mode case.But I am not quite sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I assume you are comfortable with the rules of [Weyl symmetrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Weyl_transform#Properties) where you may parlay the $[x,p]=i\hbar$ commutation relation to the $[a,a^\dagger]=1$ one... the combinatorics is identical provided you keep track of the *i*s and the *ħ*s, etc...

So your surmise is sound. Since different modes commute with each other,
they don't know about each other, and you Weyl-symmetrize each mode factor separately.

So, e.g., for your example, 
$$
a_1^\dagger a_1    a_2^\dagger a_2=   a_2^\dagger a_2 a_1^\dagger a_1      = \frac{a_1^\dagger a_1 + a_1 a_1^\dagger -1}{2}  ~ \frac{a_2^\dagger a_2 + a_2 a_2^\dagger -1}{2},
$$
etc.
All you need to recall is that each mode is in a separate (Fock) space of a tensor product, so all operations factor out into a tensor product of Weyl-symmetrized factors.

This is the reason all multimode/higher-dim phase space generalizations of all these distributions functions are essentially trivial, and most subtleties are routinely illustrated through just one mode.

---

*Edit in response to comment on entangled states*. One of the co-inventors of the industry, Groenewold, in his [monumental 1946 paper](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/soysoy/20Groenewold46.pdf), Section 5.06 on p 459, details exactly how to handle entangled states--in his case for the EPR state. The entanglement and symmetrization is transparent at the level of phase-space parameters (Weyl symbols): the quantum operators in the Wigner map are still oblivious of different modes. What connects/entangles them, indirectly, are the symmetrized δ-function kernels involved, even though this is a can of worms that even stressed Bell's thinking. The clearest "modern" paper on the subject is [Johansen 1997](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9709007.pdf), which, through its factorized Wigner function and changed +/- coordinates, reassures you you *never* have to bother with the quantum operators: the entangling is all in the Wigner function and phase-space, instead! (Illustration: [351884/66086](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/351884/66086).)

Comment: I know the fact that operators belonging to different mode commute. But I do no think they necessarily " don't know about each other" because the different mode maybe entangled. For example, in some cases the photon number in one mode is always the same as the photon number in some other mode. I agree with what you said in the cases where there is no entanglement.

Answer (score 0):

[A quasiprobability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiprobability_distribution) depends on the symbol/operator ordering prescription. E.g.:

1. For Weyl/symmetric ordering of Hermitian operators, one uses the [Wigner quasiprobability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution).
2. For Wick/normal ordering of creation & annihilation operators, one uses the [Glauber–Sudarshan $P$ representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glauber%E2%80%93Sudarshan_P_representation).
3. For anti-normal ordering of creation & annihilation operators, one uses the [Husimi $Q$ representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husimi_Q_representation).

Comment: I knew that  the ordering is related to P Q and W function. But my question here is to find out what is the definition of symmetrically ordering in mult-imode case. I have read the paper "
Density Operators and Quasiprobability Distributions" but it only talked about single mode case...

Answer (score 0):

Symmetrically order expansion of the ladder operator is written as follows;

a1b1=1/2(a1b1 +b1a1)= a1b1+1/2

a=creation operator b= anihilatinoperator, also

a1b1a2b2=1/2(a1b1 +b1a1)1/2(a2b2+b2a2)= (a1b1+1/2)(a2b2+1/2)=a1b1a2b2+1/2(a1b1)+1/2(a2b2)+1/4

Comment: Could you please use [MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for the formulas to make them readable.

Answer (score 0):

Symmetrically order expansion of the ladder operator is written as follows;

$$a_1 b_1 =  (a_1 b_1 + b_1 a_1)/2= a_1 b_1 + 1/2$$

where $a$ is the creation operator and $b$ is the annihilation operator, also

$$a_1 b_1 a_2 b_2 = \frac{1}{2} (a_1 b_1 + b_1 a_1) \frac{1}{2}(a_2 b_2+b_2 a_2) = (a_1 b_1+ \frac{1}{2})(a_2 b_2+ \frac{1}{2}) = a_1 b_1 a_2b_2+  \frac{1}{2}(a_1 b_1)+\frac{1}{2}(a_2 b_2) + \frac{1}{4}$$