# Wigner transformation of operator $X_1P_2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, wigner-transform

Suppose I have a gaussian wigner function $W(X1, X2,p1, p1)$. For example it could be the wigner function of two modes squeezed vaccume state.   I need to find the expectation value of operator $X_1P_2+P_2X_1$  and $X_2X_1+X_1X_2$  using wigner function. Basically my goal is to find covarience matrix of the two modes entangled state. How does this kind of calculaions work? as my operators are symmetric I'm trying to use the properties for seymetric operators. Thanks in advance

Comment: Related [349778](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/349778/definition-of-symmetrically-ordered-operator-for-multi-mode-case/349792#349792). Are you guys in the same class? Is the Groenewold section 5.06 answer adequate for you? One never entangles operators and their Wigner transforms. One entangles states, and their Wigner functions, instead.

Comment: So the problem is unanswerable *unless* you provide the Wigner function, or even the wave function of the entangled state you have in mind---obviously you are not thinking of Groenewold's (5.21), or (2.97).

Comment: my wingner function is a gaussian wigner function in terms of x_1,x_2,p_1 and p_2. And I need to find the expectation value of   x_1x_2+x_2x_1  or x_1p_2+p_2x_1. How does the symmetrically ordered operator can be used for this kind of problems?

Comment: The Johanssen paper linked does this for you. There is *no* operator ordering ambiguity, but you *must* have the correct Wigner function, *explicitly* and then it is just a dumb integral. In any case, you can't ask a question without providing the exact Wigner function of the entangled state involved. Perhaps you could edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Can you please put the link of the paper in the comment?

Comment: ? the related question link is not good enough? In any case, [Groenewold 1946](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/soysoy/20Groenewold46.pdf) and [Johanssen  1997](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9709007.pdf). Might practice techniques from [this one](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf), or comparable texts in the market.

Comment: So I think this is the right way to do it. First I need to write down the opertators in terms of anihilation and creation operators. For example :

Comment: So I think this is the right way to do it. First I need to write down the opertators in terms of anihilation and creation operators. For example :$X1P2 +=(a†1+a1)(a2- a†2)/(2i)$. The I try to make it symmetric. Finally I replace the anihilaion and creation operators with their equvalence in terms of q and p and use it to find  expectation value. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Im a little confused as I want to use symmetry for X1P2 not for annihilation and creation operators. All references talk about anihilation and creation. Sorry if I'm being stupid, I'm undergrad student.

Comment: what's the wigner transform or operator X1P2+P2X1? thats my question.

Comment: $2x_1p_2$, what else? see tentative answer.

Comment: There should be a way to prove it using the definition of wigner transform, anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: @CosmasZachos you can see how I found my wigner function here : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/351771

Comment: I understand the wigner transforms of bilinears already thanks to the references that you gave to me, but I think the problem is my calculation of wigner function!

Answer (score 1):

OK, by all appearances you may be interested in a Wigner function such as 
$$
W=\frac{1}{\pi^2}  e^{-s^2 Q^2} e^{-P^2/s^2}  e^{-q^2/s^2} e^{-s^2f^2},
$$
where 
$$
Q=(x_1+x_2)/\sqrt{2}, \\
q=(x_1-x_2)/\sqrt{2}, \\
P=(p_1+p_2)/\sqrt{2}, \\
f=(p_1-p_2)/\sqrt{2}.
$$
Consequently
$$
x_1=(Q+q)/\sqrt{2},
$$
etc. 
You know how to take expectation values of the simple independent gaussian variables,
$$
\langle Q^2\rangle= \int dqdQdfdP ~ Q^2 W= 1/s^2,\\
\langle q^2\rangle= \int dqdQdfdP ~ Q^2 W= s^2,\\
\langle Q P\rangle= \int dqdQdfdP ~ QP W= 0,
$$
...etc.
So, then *any correlation between momenta and coordinates will vanish, while
$$
\langle Q^2 +q^2\rangle =\langle x_1^2+ x_2^2 \rangle = s^2 + 1/s^2, \\
\langle Q^2-q^2 \rangle =  \langle 2x_1 x_2 \rangle =1/s^2- s^2 \\
\langle P^2 +f^2\rangle =\langle p_1^2+p_2^2\rangle =  s^2 + 1/s^2,
$$
etc...
You know, from symmetry, $\langle x_1^2\rangle= \langle x_2^2\rangle$, and so on.
You should be able to do the rest.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do this part, but I think my Wigner fuction is wrong! Can you please take a look at my calculation for the wigner fuction?

Comment: Sorry, enough, pal..... There are superb reviews on the subject. Try the W function with just One mode, to unconfuse yourself.