# Wigner function for composite systems?

Tags: quantum-information, wigner-transform

How is it possible to find the Wigner function for composite systems? In particulr, for a composite system which in the product state we know that $\psi_{AB}(x_A,x_B)=\psi_{A}(x_A)\,\psi_{B}(x_B)$. But, how can we compute the integral $W(x_{AB},p_{AB})=\int dy\,\psi^*_{AB}(x_{AB}+y)\,\psi_{AB}(x_{AB}-y)e^{2ip_{AB}y/h}$? Specifically, in the previous formula, what should be written as the momentum of the composite system, $p_{AB}$?

Comment: Possibly [related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/350241/wigner-transformation-of-operator-x-1p-2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for your given pure decoupled product state, $\psi(x_A,x_B)=\psi_{A}(x_A)\,\psi_{B}(x_B)$, 
think of how you'd write down the Hilbert-space density matrix for that state, and then Wigner-transform that.

Your answer is straightforward,
$$W(x_A,x_B,p_A, p_B)=\int dy_A dy_B ~\psi^*_A(x_A+y_A)\,\psi_A(x_A-y_A) ~\psi^*_B(x_B+y_B)\,\psi_B(x_B-y_B)~~e^{2i(p_A y_A+p_B y_B )/h} .$$

In [EPR-type considerations](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9806069), [or](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9806069), people often take $\pm$ "light-cone" or c.m. variable combinations, but you get the idea. Your function is simply the plain generic generalization of 4-d phase space.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Now, I can completely understand the concept.